# How do I move the caret to the current indentation level in Resharper 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-10.0

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper 10 and noticed that whenever I click on a line of code, the caret is placed at exactly the position I clicked regardless of whether the line has sufficient length. It seems the line is filled with blanks as required.

This is pretty annoying in empty lines where I'd like to have the caret at the current indentation level and not dozens of characters into the line. Is there a shortcut to move the caret to the beginning of the line (with indentation) or do I have to switch of this new behavior completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio you may have the 'Enable virtual space' selected, `Tools`->`Options`->`Text Editor`->`C#`->`General`

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not 100% the answer to my question but I'll accept it, since it solves my problem. I find this feature rather annoying, so I'll switch it off completely.